# Как значение цикла записать в String?

Tags: java, массивы, случайные-числа

Всем привет. У меня такой вопрос. Хочу сделать чтобы char заполнялся Random-но столькими значениями сколько захочет пользователь. Столкнулся с проблемой, что всегда возвращает только одно значение, т.к. каждый раз заходя в цикл, значение переписывается и по факту сохраняется последнее.

```
private static char codeGenerator(int needCharacters) {
    Random r = new Random();
    String alphabet = "123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    for (int i = 0; i < needCharacters; i++) {
        generatedCode = alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(alphabet.length()));
    }
    return generatedCode;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Компилятора под рукой нету, но должно получиться что-то вроде такого :

```
private static String codeGenerator(int needCharacters) {
    Random r = new Random();
    String genstring; // Создаём результирующую строку для сгенерированных символов
    String alphabet = "123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    for (int i = 0; i < needCharacters; i++) {
        generatedCode = alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(alphabet.length()));
        genstring = genstring + Character.toString(generatedCode); ; // А здесь просто добавляем к результирующей строке наш рандумный символ, заранее переведя в строку (toString) 
    }
    return genstring; // А здесь и так всё понятно (возвращаем не последний сгенерированный символ, а всю строку)
}
```

Comment: В моём случае Ваш вариант оказался наилучшим. Спасибо.

Comment: @Maksims да не за что 

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy  Вы может хоть StringBuilder в код добавите а то совсем не по феншую плодить столько обьектов...;)

Comment: @PeterSlusar ну в принципе можно и "Билдером" воспользоваться, но новичку это будет чуть сложнее понять :)

Answer (score 2):

Вам следуте обьявить массив типа char и записаывать возвращаемые значения в этот массив:

```
private static char[] codeGenerator(int needCharacters) {
    Random r = new Random();
    String alphabet = "123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    char result[] = new char[needCharacters];
    for (int i = 0; i < needCharacters; i++) {
        result[i] = alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(alphabet.length()));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Обратите внимание что размер массива и есть собственно запрашиваемое колличество пользователем символов.